# To pass value from dropdownlist(binded to a database) to textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a database table as below :

```
  Create table tblState
  (
   StateId int primary Key,
   StateName nvarchar(50)
  )
```

which is binded to a database as below :

```
  protected void BindStateDropDown()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblState", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlState.DataSource = ds;
        ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddlState.DataValueField = "StateId";
        ddlState.DataBind();
    }
    ddlState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}
```

Now i want to pass the selected text from dropdownlist to the textbox on buttonclick.I have used the below code which passes the VALUE.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function calculateState() {

  var state = document.getElementById('<%= ddlState.ClientID%>');
  var txtState0 = document.getElementById('<%= txtState.ClientID%>');
  txtState0.value = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  </script>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Width="260px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateId" runat="server">
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <input id="btnState" onclick="calculateState();" type="button" value="Calculate State" />
```

How can i pass the text for the same selected option in dropdownlist to the textbox on buttonclick.It is understood that having a 'Text' attribute will work but i dont know how do i go about it.

Update - Source code added :

```
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style21">
            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label11" class="auto-style31">State:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtState" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtState" style="width:260px;" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState">
<option value="0">---Select---</option>
<option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
<option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="4">Assam</option>
<option value="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
<option value="7">Chhattisgarh</option>
<option value="8">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
<option value="9">Daman and Diu</option>
<option value="10">Delhi</option>
<option value="11">Goa</option>
<option value="12">Gujarat</option>
<option value="13">Haryana</option>
<option value="14">Himachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="15">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
<option value="16">Jharkhand</option>
<option value="17">Karnataka</option>
<option value="18">Kerala</option>
<option value="19">Lakshadweep</option>
<option value="20">Madhya Pradesh</option>
<option value="21">Maharashtra</option>
<option value="22">Manipur</option>
<option value="23">Meghalaya</option>
<option value="24">Mizoram</option>
<option value="25">Nagaland</option>
<option value="26">Orissa</option>
<option value="27">Pondicherry</option>
<option value="28">Punjab</option>
<option value="29">Rajasthan</option>
<option value="30">Sikkim</option>
<option value="31">Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value="32">Tripura</option>
<option value="33">Uttar Pradesh</option>
<option value="34">Uttarakhand</option>
<option value="35">West Bengal</option>

 </select>
        &nbsp;
 <input id="btnCity" onclick="calculateState();" type="button" value="Calculate State" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the `text` property like this:-

```
function calculateCity() {
    var city = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID%>');
    var txtState0 = document.getElementById('<%= txtState.ClientID%>');
    txtState0.value = state.options[state.selectedIndex].text;
 }
```

**Edit:**
Okay you didn't mentioned its wrapped inside a master page,please make sure you have these scripts in content page and not master page.

Comment: I have already tried the above,comes up as 'undefined' in the textbox.

Comment: Have you checked the casing properly? This should work, its working perfectly for me.

Comment: If i dont bind the dropdownlist to a database and include items dynamically with Text & Value,the above works for me too.But this comes from a database and it might not have a Text attribute defined.How do i do that? Thats what i mean i guess.

Comment: Nope it has nothing to do with database code, can you show the page source generated?

Comment: A liitle correction.There is not city variable.They are all states like var state,ddlState,txtState.Anyways,I made the above changes : and it says 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.The above controls are not inside the masterpage though.The page just has a masterpage.

Comment: Yeah I agree, But your this content page is wrapped inside a master page right? That's why it is generating the id as `ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState`. I have exactly produced the same scenario like binding dropdown from DB and including a master page, but for me its working fine. Please once again cross check, you have typed everything correct because in JS even a single case can show unexpected result.